# Return promise from dispatch function inside .map() method

Tags: javascript, promise, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using `redux-thunk` to manage some side effects. The problem is the following. Somewhere in my react component I have a function which is responsible for fetching all necessary data once the component mounts or gets new props namely `fetchRequiredData()`.

Within `fetchRequiredData()` I'm looping over an array as each key needs to fetch some data. I need to be able to have an overaching promise which only resolves when the promises inside the `.map()` are resolved. If I don't have this the page runs into trouble as it tries to render things it can't.

**Simplified code example**

```
export const fetchRequiredData = (requiredAccounts) => (dispatch) => {
    // How to wrap the promises inside the .map() into 1 "big" promise?
    requiredAccounts.map(account => {
        dispatch(fetchAccount(account)); // Returns a promise
    });
}
```

In my component I should be able to do the following

```
class Accounts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pending: true;
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({pending: true});
        this.props.fetchRequiredData().then(() => this.setState({pending: false}));
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        this.setState({pending: true});
        this.props.fetchRequiredData().then(() => this.setState({pending: false}));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map all promises into an array and then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function to resolve them all:

```
const allPromises = requiredAccounts.map(account => {
    return dispatch(fetchAccount(account)); // Returns a promise
});
Promise.all(allPromises).then(() => {
  // ... do something after all promises were resolved ...
});
```